# Why last row of Datagridview can't sort?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

This is my code:

```
string ColumnName_Idx="Idx";
```

Form Load:

```
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        col1.DataPropertyName = "FLAG";
        col1.Name = "FLAG";           
        col1.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
        DGV_List.Columns.Add(col1);

        DGV_List.Columns.Add(ColumnName_Idx, ColumnName_Idx);
        DGV_List.Columns[ColumnName_Idx].Visible = true;
        DGV_List.Columns[ColumnName_Idx].DataPropertyName  =ColumnName_Idx ;
        DGV_List.Columns[ColumnName_Idx].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic ;


        DataTable oData = new DataTable();
        oData.Columns.Add("FLAG", typeof(bool));
        oData.Columns.Add("FLAG_BASE", typeof(bool));
        oData.Columns.Add("FLAG_SELECT", typeof(bool));
        oData.Columns.Add("GROUP_NAME");
        oData.Columns.Add("TOOL_NAME");
        oData.Columns.Add("MODEL_TRIAL_NO");
        oData.Columns.Add(ColumnName_Idx, typeof(int));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = oData.NewRow();

            if(i==1)
                dr["FLAG"] = true ;
            else
               dr["FLAG"] = false;
            dr["FLAG_BASE"] = false;
            dr["FLAG_SELECT"] = false;
            dr["MODEL_TRIAL_NO"] = "test" + i;
            oData.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
   

        DGV_List.DataSource = oData;
        DGV_List.Sort(this.DGV_List.Columns["FLAG"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Event Cell click:

```
private void DGV_List_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  
        this.DGV_List.BeginEdit(true);
        for (int i = 0; i < DGV_List.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DGV_List.Rows[i].Cells[ColumnName_Idx].Value = i+1;
        }                
        this.DGV_List.EndEdit();
        DGV_List.Sort(this.DGV_List.Columns[ColumnName_Idx], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        
}
```

Last row of DatagridView can't sort correct when i click on checkbox column.

Result:

[image]

This is expect result:

[image]

Why last row of Datagridview can't sort?

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions as to what you are trying to do here. So to just get to the point… I am confident the problem you describe is coming from the fact that the code is adding the values to the “GRID Cells” instead of adding the values to the grids `DataSource` cells.

Bear in mind, That `IF` a `DataGridView` has a `DataSource` … `THEN` … technically, you can sort the grid in one of two ways… 1) you can sort the “GRID” as your current code does… OR … 2) you can sort the grid by sorting the grids “DATASOURCE.” Obviously you may get undesired results if you mix the two.

First and probably the most relevant aspect of this is that `IF` you sort the “GRID” as your code currently does… `THEN` … after the sort… the grid rows and the underlying `DataRows` in grids `DataSource` may not necessarily be in the same order. The same idea applies if you filter the GRID. In almost ALL cases the underlying data source remains untouched when you sort the GRID.

It is very unclear “why” you would put the sorting code in the grids `CellClick` event… ? … With this, EVERYTIME the user clicks a cell, then the grid is re-sorted… ? … this is very odd and clearly unnecessary in 99% of the cell clicks since the grid is already sorted.

To proffer a simple solution, I suggest… that when the code sets the “idx” numbers… instead of looping through the GRID rows and set each cell… that instead you loop through the grids `DataSource` rows and set the cells there as opposed to the grid cells. The code below appears to do as you are wanting… but again this is unclear.

```
private void DGV_List_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  DataTable gridTable = (DataTable)DGV_List.DataSource;
  for (int i = 0; i < gridTable.Rows.Count; i++) {
    gridTable.Rows[i][ColumnName_Idx] = i + 1;
  }
  DGV_List.Sort(this.DGV_List.Columns[ColumnName_Idx], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for… then… please edit your question to clarify what you are trying to accomplish. And lastly, you should without a doubt remove the sorting from the grids `CellClick` event.

Comment: I have to keep order of Datagridview, If change datasource, it is not correct.

Comment: I want turn off Sort while editting CellValue ( still allow sort when click on header). So i added a tmp Column to keep index of target rows.

Comment: _”I have to keep order of Datagridview, If change datasource, it is not correct.”_ … where is my code “changing” the datasource order?

Comment: _”I want turn off Sort while editting CellValue ( still allow sort when click on header).”_ … then “unsort” the grid before you set the values. The code is sorting the grid at the end of the forms load event. You can either turn off the sorting done in the forms load event or use my solution… both will produce the same thing. Again… it is not clear “what” you are wanting here. Can you show this with an example?

Comment: In load event: I sorted by "FLAG" and i want keep this order while i editting.

Comment: _”In load event: I sorted by "FLAG" and i want keep this order while i editting.”_ … then you will need to sort the grid by `Flag` AND `Idx.` Currently using your posted code, if you click a cell the first time… it will produce what the picture shows… however… if you click a different cell… then the grid will sort the `idx` column as expected. Again, please show an example of what you are expecting. As I said before, you are not telling us “what” you expect the grid to look like after the user clicks a cell.

Comment: Thank you, i update a image in my question (desired result).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239927/discussion-between-d-t-and-johng).